# Power BI Percentage of Total

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to get a column to display in a table that will display Users as a percentage of total users. I can get this to work using a calculated column but this does not work with a slicer that allows the user to filter the data. It always calculates against the total of the unfiltered column and not the user filtered column.

I think I need a measure but I can't figure out how to do it.

What I want is :

Users Value / Sum(Users Value Column)

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This was my solution

```
Measure = 
    Selectedvalue('dataName'[Users])
    /
    Calculate(sum([Users]),allselected('DataName'[column]))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to your answer @jhib, it's better to change your DAX to this:

```
% of Total =
VAR allusers =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Users] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'DataName'[column] ) )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'dataName'[Users] ), allusers )
```

This way you will not experience a "Divide by zero error" if the data has zero's in the future...